# How to do I know the progress or how to show a progress bar when a calculation is being done inside a matrix in Python?

Tags: python, matrix

I want to know the progress or how to show a progress bar when a calculation is being done inside a matrix in Python? Can someone help me out please?

Show a progress bar when a calculation is being done inside a matrix in Python

Comment: How are you doing the matrix calculation? If you have a `for` loop, you can have it print something periodically. If you're using numpy, I don't think it has a way to do this.

Comment: [`tqdm`](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) is a commonly used library for this kind of thing

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Unfortunately, I am using numpy for matrix calculation. I thought there's a way to do it. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used numpy.sin as an example for matrix calculation and looped.

I used also tqdm.

Hope the sample code helps:

```
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm

# Define the dimensions of the matrix
rows = 20000
columns = 20000

# Create the matrix (random example)
matrix = np.random.rand(rows, columns)

# Create an empty result matrix
result = np.zeros((rows, columns))

# Iterate over each element of the matrix and show a progress bar
for i in tqdm(range(rows)):
    result[i, :] = np.sin(matrix[i, :])  # Your calculation goes here

# Calculation complete
print("Matrix calculation finished!")
print(result)
```